# Calculating the perimeter of any triangle [python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am following an online course on python, and am stuck on this activity:

> Assume distance2D(x1, y1, x2, y2) has already been defined. Using it, define a function trianglePerimeter(xA, yA, xB, yB, xC, yC) which calculates the perimeter of a triangle whose three points are (xA, yA), (xB, yB) and (xC, yC).

Now distance2D is a function to calculate the distance between two points:

> Assume hypotenuse(a, b) has already been defined. Using it, define a function distance2D(x1, y1, x2, y2) which calculates the distance between the point (x1, y1) and the point (x2, y2).

Hypotenuse is just to calculate the hypotenuse of a right-angle triangle. The site is asking me to use the distance2D function to define the trainglePerimeter function.

The following is my code.

```
def trianglePerimeter(xA,yA,xB,yB,xC,yC):
    a = distance2D(xA,yA,xB,yB)
    b=distance2D(xB,yB,xC,yC)
    return a+b
```

Other than just that, I have tried altering the code, and nothing seems to work. Can someone *please* help me!

error message i get:

> Before running your code: We defined a function distance2D. 
>   Program executed without crashing.
>   The grader said:
>   Running trianglePerimeter(0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0) … Error: trianglePerimeter(0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0) has wrong value 10.0, expected 12.0

Comment: Where is your function `distance2D`?

Comment: For a triangle having sides equal to a, b and c, your formula to compute the perimeter is very very strange (a * b - b). [There you have the right formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perimeter).

Comment: Do you know what the "perimeter" of a polygon refers to? I don't understand where you got the formula you're using, but it has nothing to do with calculating a triangle's perimeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input triangle has sides of lengths 3, 4, and 5. The perimeter of a polygon is equal to the sum of the lengths of its sides. For this triangle, that would be 3+4+5, or 12. However, you are multiplying two of the side lengths, then subtracting one of those side lengths from that product, for 3*5-5, or 10. I do not know why you are doing this. Simply get the length of each side and then add them all up:

```
def trianglePerimeter(xA,yA,xB,yB,xC,yC):
    a = distance2D(xA, yA, xB, yB)
    b = distance2D(xB, yB, xC, yC)
    c = distance2D(xC, yC, xA, yA)
    return a+b+c
```

Comment: I actually accidentally pasted the wrong piece of code and didn't proofread. My actual code that I did, was similar to yours, but i skipped the  c variable and returned a+b. Sorry, I'll try your code. :)

Answer (score 1):

See this

```
import math
def distance2D(xA,yA,xB,yB):
    return math.sqrt((xA-xB)*(xA-xB)+(yA-yB)*(yA-yB))

def trianglePerimeter(xA,yA,xB,yB,xC,yC):
    return distance2D(xA,yA,xB,yB)+distance2D(xA,yA,xC,yC)+distance2D(xC,yC,xB,yB)

print trianglePerimeter(1,5,6,2,7,6)
16.0368200508
```

Answer (score 1):

My code ended up like this:

```
a = 0
b = []
triangle = {
'v1': [input('Write the coordinates for the first vector: ') for x in range(2)],
'v2': [input('Write the coordinates for the second vector: ') for x in range(2)],
'v3': [input('Write the coordinates for the third vector: ') for x in range(2)]
}
for z, y in triangle.items():
    for x in y:
        a = int(x)**2 + a
    b.append(a**(1/2))
    a = 0

print(sum(b))
```

First I gave a = 0, and b = [] so I could use them for adding the vector lengths. Then I created a dictionary of lists, each list containing a bi-dimensional vector. Then I used a for for going though each list, and another one to go though each value inside the list. I then proceeded with the math, and appended the values inside another list - b.
After going though all the lists inside the dict, my code printed the sum of all the b list values.

Feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate perimeter add the distance of three sides. Your equation is definitely not doing that.

```
def perimeter(xA,yA,xB,yB,xC,yC):
    len_a = distance2D(xA,yA,xB,yB)
    len_b = distance2D(xB,yB,xC,yC)
    len_c = distance2D(xC,yC,xA,yA)
    return len_a + len_b + len_c
```

You will correctly get answer as 12 for the given sides.